# python で sorted dict を実現するパッケージは？

Tags: python

python において、以下の要件を満たすライブラリを探しています。

- `obj.set(key, val)` で key に対して値を store できる。 O(log(N)) で実行できる。
- `obj.get(key)` で store した key を取得できる。これが O(log(N)) で実行できる。
- `obj.find_sup(key)` で、過去 store した key の中で、今与えられている key より小さいもしくは等しいもののうち最大のものが取得できる。それが O(log(N)) で実行できる。

基本的なデータ構造なので、割と需要は高いと思っていますが、このような要件の時に利用される定番のパッケージはありますか？

Comment: 計算量については保証されていませんが、記載された `set` `get` `find_sup` は標準ライブラリの `collections.OrderedDict` を利用して実装するのが良いかもしれません。 [collections --- コンテナデータ型 — Python 3.7.3 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)